# Best approach of using the same (locale) git repo in Windows and in Linux

Tags: linux, windows, git, version-control

What is the best approach if I want to use the same (locale) git repo in Windows and in Linux without using any servers? And what pitfalls are to avoid?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about accessing the same repository (the files git uses) from both Windows and Linux (dual boot sharing a filesystem?), the things I can think off the top of my head as problematic are character encoding (most Linux distributions have made the transition to UTF-8 by now, I'm not clear what Windows is using right now; this will affect configuration and checked out files). The other point is line endings (for once, Microsoft went with the ASCII standard and ends lines by NL CR, Unix/Linux went the stringy route and uses just NL). But note that I'm a happy git user on Linux since it's beginnings, and I'm also a happy non-user of Windows for much of the same time.

It gives me a unconfortable feeling anyway, some glitch in this (most probably totally untested) scenario could make you lose *everything*. There are alternatives that allow to set up private repositories for free on the 'net, like [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org). Setting one up has the added benefit that it gives you a backup in case your machine decides to join the cloud for good some day...